# Not able to download complete source code of a web page

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape [this](https://www.udemy.com/topic/financial-analysis/?lang=en%27) web-page using python requests library.
But I am not able to download complete html source code. When I use my web-browser to inspect elements, it gives complete html, which I believe can be used for scraping, but when I access this url using python requests library, those html tags which have data are simply disappeared and I am not able to scrape data from those. Here is my sample code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib
import http.client
url  = 'https://www.udemy.com/topic/financial-analysis/?lang=en'
user_agent='my-user-agent'
request = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BS(html,'html.parser')
```

can anybody please help me out?? Thanks

Comment: Page loads content dynamically. Depending on what you actually want from page you will need browser automation or possibly see if dev tools shows you any uris which feed content of interest you can use with requests. What do you actually want from the page?

Comment: One thing to note while doing web crawling when you do `inspect element` it will show you current state of webpage (all elements including ones that are loaded using JS.) The code you wrote will return initial page. To view initial page source code use `view-source` option of browser.

Answer (score 1):

The page is likely being built by javascript, meaning the site sends over the same source you are pulling from urllib, and then the browser executes the javascript, modifying the source to render the page you are seeing

You will need to use something like selenium, which will open the page in a browser, render the JS, and then return the source e.g.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/topic/financial-analysis/?lang=en")
driver.page_source # or driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using the stdlib module urllib2, it will allow you to comfortably get web resources.
Example:
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.de")
page_source = response.read()

AND...

For parsing the code, have a look at BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you both, @blakebrojan i tried your method,, but it opened a new chrome instance and display result there,, but what i want is to get source code in my code and scrape data from that code ... here is the code

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\chrome-driver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/topic/financial-analysis/?lang=en")

html=driver.page_source
```